# ConstraintLayout from bottom to top

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have layout like this:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="300dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/recyclerView"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_min="300dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

`FragmentContainerView` and `RecyclerView` have dynamic sizes, and `FragmentContainerView` should not be less than `300dp` and fit all available spase. `RecyclerView` should be on the bottom and can contains from 1 to 20 items. Current solution works ok only for case  `RecyclerView` contains few items, but for other case it overlaps `FragmentContainerView`.
Is it possible to align `RecyclerView` to bottom but restrict max size to have free space = 300dp at the top?

Comment: can you add some screenshot what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to do:

- Add  `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/container"` to the `RecyclerView`
- Remove `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/recyclerView"` From the `FragmentContainerView`

This will make the `FragmentContainerView` height not restricted to the height of the `RecyclerView` .. and Make the `RecyclerView` height limited between the bottom of the  `FragmentContainerView` & the bottom of the parent.

Comment: in my case FragmentContainerView also have a large height, so it overlaps the recyclerview :( but i've got your idea, will try to do something similar. thanks

Comment: @Siarhei what if you set `android:maxHeight="400dp"` to the `FragmentContainerView` .. but be cautious for the small screen devices

Comment: yes, it seems it is better solution to set constraint maxHeight with specific value for each device size. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/container"` in RecyclerView